# Cannot add custom keyboard shortcut

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys

I'm trying to assign custom shortcut to launch my own script (I don't need it in terminal window, just launch it)

So, I went to Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts, pressed the button with "+" and entered the name of shortcut and the command itself. But then I cannot bind keys to that shortcut. I selected a new row and pressed needed keys (Shift + F3) and nothing happens. I can change the keys for system shortcuts, but do not have any luck with my own.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For custom shortcuts, you can't bind your keyboard shortcut if you only selected the row. This is different from how it works for *System* shortcuts, where merely selecting the row is enough to input a new keyboard shortcut.

[image]

You have to click on the *Disabled* and wait for it to change to *New accelerator...*. After that you can press your desired keyboard shortcut and it will be reflected appropriately.

[image]