# Enabling native shortcuts on Gnome - 3

Tags: 12.04, gnome

How can I enable the native shortcuts like

- Alt + Ctrl + T: Terminal
- Alt + Ctrl + D: Show Desktop

on Gnome 3.

Comment: Note: this is still totally broken on 12.10 and gnome3.4.2. see the reference bugs on the top answer for workarounds.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

GNOME 3.4 uses gsettings for the keyboard shortcuts while Ubuntu still uses gconf for the keyboard shortcuts. Because of this, there is no easy way to enable the native shortcuts for gnome-shell.

If you really want to use them, you need to manually enable them in order for them to work.

For terminal's keyboard shortcut, search for *Keyboard* in the gnome-shell overview and open it.

Move to *Custom Shortcuts* and add a new shortcut by clicking on the + button. Add a relevant name to the shortcut. Input *gnome-terminal* for the command and add the keyboard shortcut you desire.

[image]

And, for the other one, you need to have [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools] installed to enable the shortcut for *show-desktop*.

Open dconf-editor, navigate to `org` → `gnome` → `desktop` → `wm` → `keybindings` → `show-desktop` → Change the value to `'<Control><Alt>D'`.

[image]

---

If you want other options to use the native shortcuts as well, look for them in the dconf-editor in the sub options mentioned above and modify them accordingly.

References:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11834672
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/952223
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/965921

Comment: And, in case if you have any problem adding custom keyboard shortcuts - [How to add custom keyboard shortcuts?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/116227/cannot-add-custom-keyboard-shortcut/117529#117529)

Comment: Launch Terminal is already available under launchers. But it is not working

Comment: @Starx You need to create it by yourself. Or else, it won't work. See relevant [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/952223/comments/5) on the bug report.

Comment: Ok, terminal worked, now i dont have so many on below the dconf-editor. Do I have to create all that?

Comment: @starx follow the navigation: org → gnome → desktop → wm → keybindings → show-desktop. It definitely is there.

Comment: Incidentally, it appears that it's not possible to have a shortcut key Super + T for launching a terminal, due to a bug somewhere in GNOME.  :(

Comment: @MariusGedminas if you read the last link on the answer references, there's a few workarounds. it's a pain in the *** (should be gnome3 tagline) but doable. write "<Mod4>t"

Comment: Although I followed the instructions and installed the application and changed the shortcut for showing desktop as depicted in the screenshots, it does not seem to be working. Request your help with what could be the problem.

Comment: @Sudarshan If you are on 12.04 and you also tried logging out and in, I don't think I have any other solution. Maybe you can explain a bit more or start a new question?