# Not Alt + Tab to find my window

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Sometimes I open more than seven or eight window. majority of this situation one of them is terminal. also you know that we need terminal during work. So I do not like to press ALt + Tab and after that skip to gain my own window. How many times I should do this!! for an important window like terminal which I need that repeatedly . So I need any key switch which bring terminal for me Not Alt + Ctrl + T, that one open new terminal. I need my own current terminal. Any way you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Unity, the easiest way to go to a certain window is to put the application on one of the first 10 positions in the bar on the left. The windows of these applications can be directly accessed by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd><digit></kbd>. For example, the window corresponding to the first application in the left bar can be accessed by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, the second applications window by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> and so on.

If no window of the respective application is open, a new one will be opened when you press the key combination. If you want to open a new window of an application that is already open, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd><digit></kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

You can place your terminal on your second workspace.

To do this you can right click on the terminal's title bar and choose for `Move workspace right` or first go to your second workspace and open your terminal there.

To switch workspaces you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>(Arrow)</kbd> (up, down, right, left).

You can also use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to switch between applications in reverse.

Answer (score 3):

When you hold the <kbd>Super</kbd> key you will see numbers on the items of the launcher as in the screenshot below. So to open a new terminal or switch to an already open one, I would press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

[image: launcher]

Answer (score 2):

Running

```
 wmctrl -x -a gnome-terminal
```

will switch to a workspace that contains the Terminal (or one of them if you have multiple Terminals running), raise it and make it the active window (you may need to install package `wmctrl` first).

See "[Cannot add custom keyboard shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116227/cannot-add-custom-keyboard-shortcut)" for how to create a keyboard shortcut for this command.